# Add a variable test to a function

Tags: python, functional-programming

So I just asked about function lists, and now I want to see if I can, I guess make a string a non-string? I don't know quite how to word it. The idea is to pass a function a string that contains the test it should do. So the code would be something like this:

```
def newFunct(result, test):
    return (lambda x: result if(test) else "")
```

When I tried it took it as a String and always returned true.

Is there a way to cast it or something so when I called `newFunct("Even", "x%2==0")` would return `lambda x: "Even" if(x%2==0) else ""` rather than `lambda x: "Even" if("x%2==0") else ""`?

Comment: Calling a variable `str` is a bad idea as it blocks you from using the `str()` builtin.

Comment: I couldn't understand the question. Please try to improve it.

Comment: Okay that's just a convention I was used to in Java, but thanks I didn't know that.

Comment: You generally do not want to pass around expressions as strings of Python to be evaluated, for a whole lot of reasons. What are you actually trying to do that makes you think this is useful to you?

Comment: @abarnert I just learned today that I can take functions and make an array of functions from it, so I wanted to see what all I can do with it, It's mostly an academic exercise, but I'm using it to make a FizzBuzz program.

Comment: @Hovestar: But if you know you can take a _function_, why not take a function instead of a string representation of that function?

Comment: @abarnert So then I can make an array of functions, and I can make a function that can make a vast amount of other functions.

Comment: @Hovestar: Then make an array of functions _as functions_, not as strings, and make a function that makes a vast array of other functions _as functions_, not as strings. Use local `def`s, or `lambda`s, or `partial` or various other higher-order functions, to make that vast array of functions.

Comment: @abarnert Oh it's not of strings, it's accepting strings, so I could hand it an array of strings and it will make fuctions for me, which are in their own array. I'm using lambda. If you'd like to see the FizzBuzz I made with it I can edit into the question.

Comment: @Hovestar: `"x%2==0"` is a string. Where does this string come from? Why do you need it to be a string, instead of a function? If you just make it a function in the first place, and pass that function around, you won't need `eval`. And you _definitely_ don't need it for a FizzBuzz solution. If you add the code into the question, or post it on pastebin.com and add a link in a comment, we can show you how to write it without needing to pass strings around.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, but I was just learning about lambda and I want to explore capabilities of it, this is more of a learning exercise for me than an attempt at creating programs, I used it to make fizz buzz to see how it works.

Comment: @Hovestar: You don't need `eval` to explore `lambda`. Look at the second half of David Robinson's answer. That's a great example of how you to pass around functions as functions, using `lambda`. (It's also worth pointing out here that the capabilities of `lambda` are a strict subset of the capabilities of local functions in general—and that's the capabilities you _really_ want to learn. You can often create much more readable code that does exactly the same thing by using `def` instead of `lambda`.)

Comment: @abarnert Yeah thanks I just like to know all the abilities I can work with, and some I know are riskier. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with the function `eval`:

```
def newFunct(str, test):
    return (lambda x: str if eval(test, {"x": x}) else "")
is_even = newFunct("even", "x % 2 == 0")
is_even(4)
# "even"
is_even(10)
# "even"
is_even(13)
# ""
```

Note that using `eval` can be dangerous, *especially* if you are using strings that are inputted by a user. Better would be to take a function as the `test` argument:

```
def newFunct(str, test):
    return (lambda x: str if test(x) else "")
is_even = newFunct("even", lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: +1. Nice explanation of the alternative (which is also obviously easier to read and more pythonic, and probably more efficient, as well as safer).